# jar-with-dependencies and a managed dependency

Tags: maven, junit

We have a parent project with about dozen child projects. Most of the child projects have tests, and so they depend on JUnit. I thought it would make sense to pull this out to the parent pom as a managed dependency:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

In one of my child projects - still working on cleaning up this one - I need JUnit during build. So in that pom I now have:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

This works fine.
The part where things fall apart, is that this project also needs to be built as a jar with dependencies, using:

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <finalName>TestIntegration</finalName>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

The jar-with-dependencies is missing JUnit. Note that if I remove JUnit as a managed dependency, and specify it as a normal dependency in that project, then everything builds fine.

How do I get jar, as a managed dependency scoped for test, into a jar-with-dependencies?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Managed dependency is used to lock the version at the parent pom. It does not mean that junit will automatically be a dependency of child projects.

You need to specify it as a dependency in the child or in parent pom for it to be included in a uber jar

**Update**: I misunderstood the question and thought that the OP was asking about using a dependency declared in dependency mgmt only.

> How do I get jar, as a managed dependency scoped for test, into a
>   jar-with-dependencies?

Dependency management takes precedence over dependencies declared in dependency section - so redefining the dependency in dependencies with scope compile will not work. To fix this, redefine the dependency in the child pom's dependency management section.

So your parent pom has:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Add this to your child pom:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Comment: Right. So as per my second paragraph: "In one of my child projects ..." I already have that.

Comment: The child pom needs to specify a version as well.

Comment: @SiKing It worked for me without a version - it took 4.11 from parent

Comment: I'm running Maven 3.0.5, and I get: [ERROR] Internal error: org.apache.maven.artifact.InvalidArtifactRTException: For artifact {junit:junit:null:jar}: The version cannot be empty.

Comment: the scope override worked for me only if I also specified a version as well (using maven 3.3.3)

Comment: Using Maven `3.8.1` without a `version` in child POM I got `'dependencies.dependency.version' for ... is missing` error.

Comment: I created a jira for the above: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-7368

Comment: I actually got the above error with the managed dependency in the child missing `version`. When I repeated the same with unmanaged dependency in the child, I found that I can not only override just the fields that are different, they also take precedence over the attributes specified in managed dependency (tried with `scope` and `exclusions`), at least as shown by `dependency:tree`. I guess both @SiKing and @riccardo-cossu also got this error with managed dependencies only. Now, with unmanaged dependency in the child, I don't know why it won't get reflected in assembly plugin.